# Dispatching Custom Events From a Validator

Tags: apache-flex, events, validation

I have what should hopefully be a rather simple question for someone.  Basically I am trying to create a string Validator which requests a new language from its controller by dispatching an event upon its creation.

The example below is a straight copy from the Flex3 component explorer  - the only diffrence being that I have created the validator as a custom component which dispatches an event upon its creation.

The problem is that my main Application cannot hear the event being dispatched and I don't know why.

Here is the example

MyValidator.as

```
        package components 
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import mx.validators.StringValidator;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Beaker
     */
    public class MyValidator extends StringValidator 
    {

        public function MyValidator() 
        {
            trace(">>MyValidator:MyValidator--")
            var _event:Event = new Event("getLanguage", true)
            dispatchEvent(_event)
        }

    }

}
```

Main.MXML

```
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:comp="components.*" creationComplete="onComplete(event)">
     <mx:Script>
         <![CDATA[
                    import flash.events.Event;
                    import mx.controls.Alert;
                    protected function onComplete(evt:Event):void 
                    {
                        trace(">>Main:onComplete--")
                        systemManager.addEventListener("getLanguage",onTest)
                    }
                    protected function onTest(evt:Event):void 
                    {
                        trace(">>Main:onTest--")
                        Alert.show("getLanguage");
                    }
         ]]>

    </mx:Script>

    <comp:MyValidator source="{fname}" 
        property="text" 
        tooShortError="This string is shorter than the minimum allowed length of 4. " 
        tooLongError="This string is longer than the maximum allowed length of 20." 
        minLength="4" maxLength="20"  
        trigger="{myButton}" triggerEvent="click" 
        valid="Alert.show('Validation Succeeded!');"/>

    <mx:Panel title="StringValidator Example" width="75%" height="75%" 
        paddingTop="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingBottom="10">

            <mx:Form>               
                <mx:FormItem label="Enter a name between 4 and 20 characters: ">
                    <mx:TextInput id="fname" width="100%"/>
                </mx:FormItem>

                <mx:FormItem >
                    <mx:Button id="myButton" label="Validate" />
                </mx:FormItem>
            </mx:Form>  
    </mx:Panel>

</mx:Application>
```

Pardon the formatting if this isnt showing up correctly!

Answer (score 3):

Your `MyValidator` is not `DisplayObject`, so its events do not bubble. You should add listeners directly to `MyValidator` instance.

#### Variant #1:

```
<comp:MyValidator source="{fname}" 
        property="text"
        id="validator"
        tooShortError="This string is shorter than the minimum allowed length of 4. " 
        tooLongError="This string is longer than the maximum allowed length of 20." 
        minLength="4" maxLength="20"  
        trigger="{myButton}" triggerEvent="click" 
        valid="Alert.show('Validation Succeeded!');"/>
```

and

```
validator.addEventListener("getLanguage", onTest);
```

#### Variant #2:

In *MyValidator.as* add the following metadata before class declaration:

```
[Event(name="getLanguage", type="flash.events.Event")]
```

and usage:

```
<comp:MyValidator source="{fname}" 
        property="text"
        getLanguage="onTest(event)"
        tooShortError="This string is shorter than the minimum allowed length of 4. " 
        tooLongError="This string is longer than the maximum allowed length of 20." 
        minLength="4" maxLength="20"  
        trigger="{myButton}" triggerEvent="click" 
        valid="Alert.show('Validation Succeeded!');"/>
```

Comment: @Beaker, what's the problem here?

Comment: Many thanks for your response however Its still not quite right...
MyValidator.as cannot use the Metadata tag you mentioned
So I have tried two things.
Firstly I tried adding the code below to MyValidator.as:
[Metadata]
[Event(name="getLanguage", type="flash.events.Event")]
No  Joy
I then tried converting myValidator.as into mxml. 
<mx:StringValidator xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" >
 <mx:Metadata>
  [Event(name="getLanguage", type="flash.events.Event")]
 </mx:Metadata>
</mx:StringValidator>
No  Joy
Amy I implementing it wrongly?

Comment: Sorry bout the formatting - its difficult to respond in 500 chars

Comment: @Beaker, sorry, my fault. I haven't noticed, that your validator is pure AS component. You are not needed to add "[Metadata]". So just add [Event(name="getLanguage", type="flash.events.Event")] before class declaration and it should work.

Comment: Hi Timofei,  (Are you named after the Volcano on Lanzarote?)
I have tried that but still no joy... :(

in my main application I have the following..

protected function onInit(evt:Event):void 
{
trace(">>Main:onInit--")      _validator.addEventListener("getLanguage", onTest);
}

and I have added the [Event(name="getLanguage", type="flash.events.Event")]  to the as3 class.  Do I need to dispatch anything when the class is instantiated?

Comment: @Beaker, regarding name - no :) I suggested 2 variants. 1: add [Event(name="getLanguage", type="flash.events.Event")] in validator class, and add  getLanguage="onTest(event)" attribute in mxml. 2: just write validator.addEventListener("getLanguage", onTest); in onInit function. And don't forget to dispatch your event, when needed.